# How to de-serialize sub nodes in NewtenSoft from JSON file

Tags: c#, .net, json

I read a JSON file, please see below the current format. De-serialization works as expected. Now the customer has provided me with another file for which the format is slightly different. The application has to accommodate both of these formats in the future.
In the current format I basically read the value replicate field and I have to basically do the same in the new format.  In the new format the replicate field is inside a new node called Assays. I am not sure to how read through the sub node.

```
**Current Format**
    "Orders": [
            {
                "Rack": "0015",
                "SampleType": "Calibrator",
                "Position": 1,
                                                    "CalMaterialLotNumber" : "08559LF00",
                                                    "CalMaterialExpirationDate" : "07-31-2012",
                                                    "LevelName" : "Cal 1",
                "AssayNumber": 149,
                        "AssayVersion": 5,
                "Dilution": 1,
                "Replicate": 3,
                                    "Track": 1,
                        "Lane": 1,
               "ReagentMasterLot": "08559LF00",
                "ReagentSerialNumber": 65000,
                "


    **New Format**

    {
        "MCCOrders": [

            {
                "Carrier": "Z425",
                "Position": 1,
                "CalMaterialLotNumber" : "03112I000",
                "CalMaterialExpirationDate" : "02-28-2014",
                        "Assays": [
                                    { 
                                                    "AssayNumber": 1014,
                                                    "AssayVersion": 6,
                                    "Dilution": 1,
                                                    "Replicate": 3,
                                                    "MasterLotNumber": "03112I000",
                                                    "PackSerialNumber": "20001",
                                    "Comment": "TP Cal"
                                    },
```

**Members**

```
public class CategoryTypeColl
{
    public CategoryType[] MCCOrders { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryType
{
    public int Replicate { get; set; }
}
```

**Method processing the JSON file**

```
public static KeyValuePair<bool, int> CyclesCompleted(string fileName)
    {
        int cyclesCompleted = 0;
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = jss();
        bool isValid = true;
        try
        {
            //Run Newtonsoft JSON deserializer
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CategoryTypeColl>(LoadTextFromFile(fileName));
            CategoryTypeColl ctl = deserialized;

            //CategoryTypeColl ctl = ser.Deserialize<CategoryTypeColl>(LoadTextFromFile(fileName));

            if (ctl != null)
            {
                List<CategoryType> collection = (from item in ctl.MCCOrders
                                                 select item).ToList();

                foreach (var replicates in collection)
                {
                    cyclesCompleted = cyclesCompleted + replicates.Replicate;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
        return new KeyValuePair<bool, int>(isValid, cyclesCompleted);
    }
```

Comment: [generate c# classes from json](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: @I4V the sample generator that you have referenced above is working great.  Would you like to include your suggestion/link as an answer so I could accept it since my issue is resolved.

Comment: No thank you, but you can answer your own question....